# Be a blessing; what does it mean

Tags: blessing, words, parashat-lech-lecha

In Bereshit (Genesis) 12:2 HaShem tells Avraham that he should be a blessing: 
*V'heyeh Bracha*: וֶהְיֵה, בְּרָכָה

But what does it mean that someone is a blessing? Isn't all blessing from HaShem, the source of all blessing.

So i'm not asking how we can bless HaShem, I'm asking how one can be a blessing; aren't blessings (brachot?) coming from HaShem?

Comment: Clarification, please. You cited a verse. But, the question that you ask seems to be more general. When you say a "bracha", you are "blessing" G-d; not receiving the blessing from G-d. (Yes, G-d "blesses" you in other ways, but that's not the intent o fthe bracha.) Do you want to know what the word "baruch" itself means, in general, or why we make a bracha to G-d on say, food, or what G-d is saying to Abraham in the verse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does baruch atah Hashem mean?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38093/what-does-baruch-atah-hashem-mean)

Comment: *Bracha* is a noun. *Baruch* is an adjective. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @DanF, I've edited out the duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38093; see what you think.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I've edited out the duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38093; see what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Rashi to that passuk (first p'shat) says it means that Avraham and his children should have the power to give brachos; up until this point, Hashem gave the brachos, not people.